# How to use condition code in tag on asp.net page?

Tags: asp.net, data-binding

I have a repeaer on page .
I binding it .I add a image in it .

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="product" runat="server" >
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" Height="120px" Width="120px" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Image") %>' />
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:Repeater>
```

I want, if doesn't exit image in (Eval("Image")) show a special image.

It is possible to insert condition in image tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to test to see if the `Eval("Image")` is empty like this:

```
<%# Eval("Image").ToString() != String.Empty ? Eval("Image") : "DefaultImagePath" %>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. should use this :Eval("Image").ToString() != String.Empty

Comment: I have updated my answer to reflect that.  Please upvote if you feel this helped you come to your resolution and to show appreciation.  Thanks